# Having trouble copying from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have looked over a few questions on the subject, but I still haven't found a solution. Here's my code:

```
i = APPS_AuditWB.Sheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count

DeptReceivedWB.Sheets(1).Copy

With APPS_AuditWB.Sheets(3) 'Deletes Recd date over a year old
    .Cells(i + 1, 1).Paste
```

The last line is where the error occurs. I've tried PasteSpecial as well, but that only pastes the equation for i (APPS_AuditWB.Sheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count).

What's going wrong?

Comment: What error message are you getting, or what is not working, specifically?

Comment: Error 438 - Object does not support this property or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
i = APPS_AuditWB.Sheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count

DeptReceivedWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy

APPS_AuditWB.Activate
APPS_AuditWB.Sheets(3).Select
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Do you know why my code didn't work? Do I always need to activate the workbook I plan on modifying in my code?

Comment: In this case, yes, you have to activate the workbook first and then select the sheet/cell to use copy/paste.  You actually take a performance hit by copying/pasting this way and activating the sheet.  When you have time, look into modifying your code to use something like `NewRange.value = OldRange.value`